# UIStackView layout issue with UILabel

Tags: uikit, uilabel, uistackview

I have two `UILabel` inside horizontal stack view with alignment `top` and distribution `fill`.[image]

The problem is second label is taking too much space rather than its intrinsic content size.

I also had set content hugging priority of second label to `.high` but still it's taking too much space. Is there any missing do I need to implement or any ways to fix it.

Comment: I assume you have set the **Lines** of your long long text label to 0. If that is the case, your second label should auto fill the space although you set the hugging priority.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to solve this. Set `contentHugging` priority to `.required` for `Horizontal axis`.